# Unable to access Apex in namespaced scratch org

Tags: managed-package, lightning-web-components, isv, scratch-org, namespace

> Note: Checking this [potential duplicate](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/258576) didn't help.

I have a project which uses **SFDX** and **LWC** and recently converted it to have a **namespace** (later it should become a **Managed Package**). I successfully recreated the scratch org and pushed my yet *unprefixed* code to it:

I then added the namespace to my `import` statements

```
import { LightningElement, api, track } from "lwc";

import getAccounts from "@salesforce/apex/MyCtrl.getAccounts";

export default class AccountList extends LightningElement {
 ...
}
```

Now all Apex calls from LWC js are failing with:

> apex://myns.MyCtrl: No apex action available for
>   myns.MyCtrl.getAccounts

When I add the namespace to my `import` statements:

```
import { LightningElement, api, track } from "lwc";

import getAccounts from "@salesforce/apex/myns.MyCtrl.getAccounts";

export default class AccountList extends LightningElement {
 ...
}
```

I get a compile-time error stating:

> Error:(1, 1) LWC1504: Invalid module id "myns.MyCtrl.getAccounts" for
>   type "apexMethod". Explicit use of namespace "myns" in file
>   "accountList.js" is prohibited. Use default namespace "c" instead.

- Did something go wrong with my scratch org?
- I can see the namespace being active in there. It's on all the classes?
- I expected to not have to explicitly mention namespace in a namespace org!?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something was wrong with my scratch org. After I recreate it 2 times it worked without adding any namespaces. I didn't delete my question as this might happen others and then the thread is helpful.

*Thanks for everybody's help!*